# How to parse a http response getting as html?

Tags: php, json, angular, http

**home.ts**

```
this.LocationProvider.getSpecificLocation(districtid,head).subscribe(res=>{
  console.log(res),
  err=>{
    console.log(err)
  }
})
```

[image: My response]

[image: response body]
I have to parse the response to show the data in the view.i couldnt do `res.json()` it shows error as `ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1`.

**ws.php**

```
public function location(){
       $this->load->model('Coolmodel','m',true);
         $retval = array();
        if($this->input->method() === 'post') {
          $obj = json_decode($this->input->raw_input_stream);

          $id = $obj->id;
          $retval['locations']=$this->m->getlocation($id);

        }
        else{
            $retval['status'] = '1';    
            $retval['district'] = $this->m->getdistrict();
        }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($retval, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

}
```

This is my php code,Should i made any modifications?

Comment: I think the issue is with the PHP code and not angular. The PHP is supposed to send a JSON response but due to some error it is giving an html response. I believe, The response that you show is actually the error stack trace and not the response. Possible to post the PHP code?

Comment: Do you really want to parse an HTML body that seems to have been generated by PHP because the PHP code has a bug? Don't you, instead, want to fix the bug in the PHP code that I guess, should in fact generate a JSON response?

Comment: @KeerthiKumarP Qn updated

Comment: I am not that good in PHP but I can see that the Error message in the response says `Undefined property: stdClass::$id`. The issue might be in the line `$id = $obj->id;`. Can you post the contents of `LocationProvider`? Also if possible the Request payload from the UI to the PHP?